# Как получить доступ к папкам и файлам из пользовательской учетки?

Tags: c#, winapi, wpf

Пишу подобие "Проводника" Windows на WPF. Возник вопрос о получении доступа к закрытым папкам (C:\Documents and Settings; C:\System Volume Information; C:\$Recycle.bin etc) хотя бы readonly для построения дерева файловой системы и "снятия" информации о папках/файлах: дата создания/изменения, объем и т.п.. На MSDN нашел инфу о классах FileIOPermission и FileIOPermissionAccess, но попытки получить доступ ко всем папкам файловой системы с помощью методов этих классов  не удалось. Возможно есть еще какие-либо методы получения доступа в C# или WinApi, но не могу с наскока сориентироваться. Может кто-либо что-то подсказать в этом направлении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это аналог проводика, то отстраивать дерево файловой системы заранее нет смысла, займет много времени, и даже если делать в бэкграунд потоке, придется отслеживать все изменения чтобы данные были актуальными, следовательно информация нам нужна только при входе в каталог/диск.
В этом случае мы не можем получать доступ если нам не хватает прав, для получения доступа можно затребовать от пользователя логин/пароль, провести имперсонофикацию, и выполнить код с необходимыми правами. Без имперсонофикации это было бы нарушением безопасности со стороны системы.
[Пример](http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/)